# How to define an additional tooltip() in leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, gis

I am already using one tooltip() function.

```
L.tooltip({
    permanent: true,
    direction: 'center',
    className: 'text'
})
.setContent(feature.properties.text)
.setLatLng(layer.getLatLng()).addTo(map);
```

And now I need to create a new tooltip. For example with the name tooltip2().

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean you need to create a new tooltip? For the same feature? Which tooltip do you want to show?

Comment: I need to create totally new tooltip, because I am already using the first one. So I need to different another tooltips.

Comment: I am getting this arror
Renderer.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_getTooltipAnchor' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can actually go ahead and use this function multiple times!

```
L.tooltip({
  permanent: true,
  direction: 'center',
  className: 'text'
})
  .setContent("Hello")
  .setLatLng([38.8, -77.1])
  .addTo(map);

L.tooltip({
  permanent: true,
  direction: 'center',
  className: 'text'
})
  .setContent("World")
  .setLatLng([38.7, -77.1])
  .addTo(map);
```

However, it looks like you might be looping through geojson data since you are using feature and layers within your tooltip. In that case you can just write it once:

```
L.geoJSON(geojson, {
  onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
    L.tooltip({
      permanent: true,
      direction: 'center',
      className: 'text'
    })
      .setContent(feature.properties.name)
      .setLatLng(layer.getLatLng())
      .addTo(map);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

If you are asking about naming the tooltips or feature layer in order to use them again later in your code, you can just set it: `const featureLayer = L.geoJSON...` and `const text = L.tooltip...`

Here is a working example of adding popups, tooltips, feature layers to the map and adjusting popup & tooltip css, including the directional triangle:
https://repl.it/repls/NeighboringConventionalPhp